# Green Flame Blade With a +1/+2/+3 Weapon

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attack

When you make the melee spell attack roll, if you are using a magical weapon, do you gain the extra **attack bonus** on top of your spell attack bonus.

"You have a bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon. The bonus is determined by the weapon's rarity."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The damage being dealt to the secondary target is caused by your spell, not by the weapon. The weapon's enhancement bonus only applies to the attack and damage roll against the primary target.

And unless I'm looking at a different version of the spell than you, the actual text doesn't tell the user to "make a melee spell attack," but rather to "make a melee attack with a weapon."

> ...you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature
>   within the spell's range ... (SCAG p. 143)

This further reinforces the idea that the secondary fire damage has nothing to do with the otherwise normal attack, as the melee attack is likely going to be modified by STR (or maybe DEX), while the bonus fire damage is likely going to be modified by INT/WIS/CHA.

That, and the whole concept of adding a magic item's enhancement bonus to the damage of a *spell* seems like an exclusively 4th-edition practice; so it seems unlikely that it would only appear in 5th edition in one specific instance.

So in closing, here's the formulas for attack and damage caused by this spell, in my opinion:

**Melee Attack Roll** = d20 + (proficiency) + (STR mod) + (magic weapon bonus)

**Melee Damage (primary target)** = d[w] + (STR mod) + (magic weapon bonus)

**Greenflame Damage (secondary target)** = (spellcasting mod)

Comment: But you would add it to the attack roll right?

Comment: Yes. That is, the initial melee attack and damage roll against the *first* target (since that attack and damage isn't actually caused by a spell). The bonus fire damage against the *secondary* target gets no modifier from your magic sword.

Comment: That being said this attack made is done using your spellcasting attack modifier right?

Comment: Again, I may be looking at a different version of the spell than you, as I don't own the SCAG book. But the initial melee attack roll should only be using your spellcasting ability modifier if the phrase *melee spell attack* is used in the text of the spell. The one I'm looking at just says "As part of casting this spell, you make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature in range." It's not a spell attack, so it would use strength (or possibly DEX, for a finesse weapon), and not your spellcasting modifier. I'm gonna go ahead and edit my answer above, to remove all ambiguity.

Comment: @Skyler No, that is not right unless for some reason you are using your spell modified to make the attack with the melee weapon.  (Shillelagh, for example).  You make that attack that you normally make ("you must make a melee attack with a weapon" against one creature withing the spell's range.")  If you hit, another target within 5 feet takes the green flame blade damage.  You roll no dice until 5th level.  p. 143 SCAG

Comment: @Skyler In effect, these spells can be read as "When you use the Cast A Spell action for this cantrip, make a single melee weapon attack that also does...."